Model ```a > 0 implies b = 1```, where a is unbounded above
I want to model if a > 0 then b = 1, where a is an unbounded above continuous variable and b is a binary variable. If it were bounded, I could use a <= M*b, but this is not the case. I've only found formulations for these types of problems, not the unbounded case.
If it helps, a is lower bounded by 0. This makes it so we can also model exactly one of a and (1-b) must be zero. As @prubin mentions in the comments (thank you!), this actually models an equivalence, not an implication. In my situation it wouldn't make a difference.
EDIT: If nonlinearities are allowed, we can use a*(1-b) == 0. I'd rather avoid this.

What does $a$ represent in your model?

@RobPratt a slack variable that I introduce to the constraints to detect infeasibilities.

Are the other variables that appear in those constraints bounded?

@RobPratt Not necessarily.

What do those other variables represent?

@RobPratt they can represent anything. The idea is, given a random infeasible model, add slack variables to the constraints in order to identify which constraints are infeasible. In the question a represents the slack variables and b a binary variable indicating infeasible constraints. The objective would be to minimize the sum of the binary variables.

Thank you for the additional details.  As you might have inferred, I am questioning the "unbounded" requirement.  In many practical use cases, variables represent physical quantities of something and hence have natural (possibly large but finite) bounds.

@RobPratt I understood your question, but given that it's a random infeasible model, I cannot assume boundedness, nor know what the variables represent.

This can be modeled with indicator constraints or a SOS1 set. Most MIP solvers support both.

@ErwinKalvelagen I thought of SOS1 constraints, but they state that at most one variable can be non-zero, not exactly one. From the approaches I've seen regarding indicator constraints, it seems that most methods rely on big-M, and thus unboundedness. Do you know of another way?

The statement "we can also model exactly one of a and b must be zero" does not track. First, it contradicts $a>0 \implies b=1.$ Second, if we change $b$ to $1-b$ in the statement, it requires equivalence rather than implication ($a=0 \implies b=0$), which was not what you posed at the start of the question.

From the approaches I've seen regarding indicator constraints, it seems that most methods rely on big-M, and thus unboundedness. No, not at all. Indicator constraints are to be used when there are no good bounds. They may use SOS1 sets under the hood.

I thought of SOS1 constraints, but they state that at most one variable can be non-zero, not exactly one. This is not an issue.
The constraint $$a \gt 0 \implies b=1$$ for $a\ge0$ and $b\in\{0,1\}$ can be implemented with a SOS1 set as follows:
$$ \begin{aligned} & b+c=1 \\ & c \in [0,1] \\ & (a,c) \in \mathbf{SOS1}\end{aligned}$$

How is the tolerance handled for what constitutes a non-zero for a continuous variable (such as a ) in the SOS1? Is that different for different solvers?

Integer Feasibility Tolerance.

Great Idea, @ErwinKalvelagen, thank you!
